# How to create react collapse with JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-bootstrap to create `collapse` so that when I click on particular button I can see the corresponding content, but when I am doing this with JSON data it is not opening correctly

I am using this [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/)

My data

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Danial",
    "Last_name": "Smith",
    "website": "www.denial.com",
    "post": "senior Developer"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Michel",
    "Last_name": "calak",
    "website": "www.Michal.com",
    "post": "junior Developer"
  }
]
```

now what I am doing is dynamically, I am passing `id` as index and the button also the same id but still when I click on one button it is opening the both of them

**And it is opening them at last I want when I click on button that corresponding data should load below the button not at the last**

[My full Code Code-sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-dirac-4krw3?file=/src/App.js)

please check

Comment: Looks like you have a single state boolean called `open` when instead you need something like `whichPanelIsOpen` which stores the index of the currently selected panel.

Comment: @WillD How can I do like that can you help me with some example

Comment: @manishthakur it is very difficult to accomplish what you are looking for because of how you have structured your code. Someone can help you fix the code but it will look very different from what you have now. Do you only want one panel open at a time?

Comment: Here is a modified version using @WillD suggestion https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cdn-pmc36 
Ideally, you should be breaking each unit into its own components and loop over the data once

Comment: @Pablo I will not mind if my code gets modified, I just want to achieve the functionality.

Comment: @Pablo  hey that is not right what you are showing up as it is rendering only at the bottom of screen not below the button clicked, and also if I click 2nd button it render below with some space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your logic slightly.

Combine the button and the content in one loop and made the state dynamic.

So that it can work easily with dynamic Data.

See the modified return statement below -

```
return (
<div className="container-fluid companyContainer">
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <div className="container mt-2">
      <button
        className="btn btn-success form-control mr-4"
        onClick={() => setOpen(open === index ? null : index)}
        aria-controls={index}
        aria-expanded={open === index ? true : false}
      >
        {item.first_name}
      </button>
      <Fade in={open === index ? true : false}>
        <div id={index} className="mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="first_name"
                name="first_name"
                disabled={true}
                value={item.first_name}
              />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="first_name" className="labelEmploye">
                Company Name
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="last_name"
                name="last_name"
                disabled={true}
                value={item.Last_name}
              />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="last_name" className="labelEmploye">
                Industry Name
              </label>
            </div>

            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="website"
                name="website"
                disabled={true}
                value={item.website}
              />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="post" className="labelEmploye">
                Post
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="post"
                name="post"
                disabled={true}
                value={item.post}
              />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="post" className="labelEmploye">
                Post
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fade>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
);
```

[You can check the working example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-flower-hvupu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: No as you can see there is a huge gap between the two buttons, I think i need to use `Accordion` then it can be done

Comment: @manishthakur, as you can see here is a gap as well - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/#fade

Comment: Is there any way I can remove the gap ?

Comment: I am looking for this. If I will find something I will share with you

Comment: @manishthakur, There is a gap between two collapses because it uses `opacity` to show and hide the container. If you want to remove the gap between two collapses you can apply custom CSS but it will remove fade effect. please see the updated fiddle.

Comment: No problem fade is not required :)

Comment: Hey I have a very small doubt in the above solution please reply once you will be free

Comment: Yeah Manish, tell me.

Comment: here with your code i am showing onclick the collapse,  but i have one thing to do where I want i can open multiple collapse like by default 1st should be open always and when I click on 2nd the first one should not close.

Comment: @manishthakur, please see the updated fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/red-flower-hvupu?file=/src/App.js  and let me know do you want this?

Comment: Hey it is not working properly as I am clicking michel2 then michel is closing

Comment: What you exactly want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213667/discussion-between-alok-mali-and-manish-thakur).